# Why equivs failing on preventing this apt-test with 2017-1 on Debian?

Tags: installing, debian, texlive-2017

I am reading the thread answer [How to install “vanilla” TeXLive on Debian or Ubuntu?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/95373/13173) and completing mono-TeXLive setting but the test proposed by the answer `sudo apt install kile` fails, so allowing the installation of `kile` although it should be prevented by `equivs`. 
Setting up the prevention mechanism - make Debian think you installed TeXLive after successful installation with `tmlgr`

```
masi@masi:~$ sudo apt install equivs --no-install-recommends
[sudo] password for masi: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  chktex dvidvi fonts-cabin fonts-comfortaa fonts-ebgaramond fonts-ebgaramond-extra fonts-freefont-otf
  fonts-gfs-artemisia fonts-gfs-complutum fonts-gfs-didot fonts-gfs-neohellenic fonts-gfs-olga
  fonts-gfs-solomos fonts-inconsolata fonts-junicode fonts-lato fonts-lobster fonts-lobstertwo
  fonts-oflb-asana-math fonts-sil-gentium fonts-sil-gentium-basic lacheck latexdiff
  libboost-signals1.55.0 libfile-homedir-perl libfile-which-perl libpotrace0 libptexenc1 libsynctex1
  libyaml-tiny-perl libzzip-0-13 pfb2t1c2pfb ps2eps ttf-adf-accanthis ttf-adf-gillius ttf-adf-universalis
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  equivs
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 61 not upgraded.
Need to get 20.7 kB of archives.
After this operation, 147 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://ftp.fi.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main equivs all 2.0.9 [20.7 kB]
Fetched 20.7 kB in 0s (63.0 kB/s) 
Selecting previously unselected package equivs.
(Reading database ... 230892 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../archives/equivs_2.0.9_all.deb ...
Unpacking equivs (2.0.9) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.0.2-5) ...
Setting up equivs (2.0.9) ...

masi@masi:~$ mkdir -p /tmp/tl-equivs && cd /tmp/tl-equivs

masi@masi:/tmp/tl-equivs$ equivs-control texlive-local

masi@masi:/tmp/tl-equivs$ wget -O texlive-local https://www.tug.org/texlive/files/debian-equivs-2017-ex.txt--2017-06-07 23:31:19--  https://www.tug.org/texlive/files/debian-equivs-2017-ex.txt
Resolving www.tug.org (www.tug.org)... 91.121.174.77
Connecting to www.tug.org (www.tug.org)|91.121.174.77|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 2314 (2.3K) [text/plain]
Saving to: ‘texlive-local’

texlive-local              100%[=========================================>]   2.26K  --.-KB/s   in 0s     

2017-06-07 23:31:20 (71.4 MB/s) - ‘texlive-local’ saved [2314/2314]

masi@masi:/tmp/tl-equivs$ equivs-build texlive-local
dh_testdir
dh_testroot
dh_prep
dh_testdir
dh_testroot
dh_install
dh_installdocs
dh_installchangelogs
dh_compress
dh_fixperms
dh_installdeb
dh_gencontrol
dpkg-gencontrol: warning: File::FcntlLock not available; using flock which is not NFS-safe
dh_md5sums
dh_builddeb
dpkg-deb: building package `texlive-local' in `../texlive-local_2017-1_all.deb'.

The package has been created.
Attention, the package has been created in the current directory,
not in ".." as indicated by the message above!

masi@masi:/tmp/tl-equivs$ sudo dpkg -i texlive-local_2017-1_all.deb
Selecting previously unselected package texlive-local.
(Reading database ... 230917 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack texlive-local_2017-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking texlive-local (2017-1) ...
Setting up texlive-local (2017-1) ...

masi@masi:/tmp/tl-equivs$ sudo apt install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  chktex dvidvi fonts-cabin fonts-comfortaa fonts-ebgaramond fonts-ebgaramond-extra fonts-freefont-otf
  fonts-gfs-artemisia fonts-gfs-complutum fonts-gfs-didot fonts-gfs-neohellenic fonts-gfs-olga
  fonts-gfs-solomos fonts-inconsolata fonts-junicode fonts-lato fonts-lobster fonts-lobstertwo
  fonts-oflb-asana-math fonts-sil-gentium fonts-sil-gentium-basic lacheck latexdiff
  libboost-signals1.55.0 libfile-homedir-perl libfile-which-perl libpotrace0 libptexenc1 libsynctex1
  libyaml-tiny-perl libzzip-0-13 pfb2t1c2pfb ps2eps ttf-adf-accanthis ttf-adf-gillius ttf-adf-universalis
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 61 not upgraded.
```

Test fails here, since the above settings should prevent it

```
masi@masi:/tmp/tl-equivs$ sudo apt install kile
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  chktex dvidvi fonts-cabin fonts-comfortaa fonts-ebgaramond fonts-ebgaramond-extra fonts-freefont-otf
  fonts-gfs-artemisia fonts-gfs-complutum fonts-gfs-didot fonts-gfs-neohellenic fonts-gfs-olga
  fonts-gfs-solomos fonts-inconsolata fonts-junicode fonts-lato fonts-lobster fonts-lobstertwo
  fonts-oflb-asana-math fonts-sil-gentium fonts-sil-gentium-basic lacheck latexdiff
  libboost-signals1.55.0 libfile-homedir-perl libfile-which-perl libpotrace0 libptexenc1 libsynctex1
  libyaml-tiny-perl libzzip-0-13 pfb2t1c2pfb ps2eps ttf-adf-accanthis ttf-adf-gillius ttf-adf-universalis
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  konsole libkonq-common libkonq5-templates libkonq5abi1
Suggested packages:
  dblatex kile-doc kile-l10n kbibtex latex2html lilypond texlive-doc-base
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  kile konsole libkonq-common libkonq5-templates libkonq5abi1
0 upgraded, 5 newly installed, 0 to remove and 61 not upgraded.
Need to get 2,369 kB of archives.
After this operation, 6,785 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Get:1 http://ftp.fi.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main libkonq5-templates all 4:4.14.2-1 [42.6 kB]
...
Setting up kile (4:2.1.3-2) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-18+deb8u9) ...
masi@masi:/tmp/tl-equivs$ sudo apt install kile
```

OS: Debian 8.7
TeXLive: 2017

Comment: The `equivs` method does not prevent you from explicitly demanding the installation of these packages.  It only tricks the package manager into thinking that all dependencies for a TeXlive installation are fulfilled, i.e. if you install a package which requires (parts of) TeXlive the `equivs` will substitute for that.

Comment: If you want to prevent installation of `kile` use `sudo apt-mark hold kile` or use [APT pinning](https://wiki.debian.org/AptPreferences).

Comment: the whole point is to _allow_ the installation of packages such as kile without forcing a re-install of the system tex. Why would you want to prevent the installation of all packages that depend on tex?

Comment: Tlmgr does not provide kile, so of course the TL equivs package does not prevent it. It prevents the installation of the Ubuntu related texlive packages.

Comment: When you build the equivs file you downloaded a file from TUG. Did you ever look what is in the file? Hint it is a ret file that among other things lists the packages this equivs package will mark that you have installed equivalents of.

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영 that is exactly what a package manager like apt-get does, and your test with kile shows it worked, you installed kile but that did not trigger an installation of the system tex as you had told apt that you already had an equivalent package. There is no question to answer here.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle How can you force to show all times when `equivs` is active? I really would like to have explicit `equivs`.

Comment: I have no idea (I don't use apt-get) (but I don't understand your comment) do you mean can you list all the debian packages that you could potentially install that have a dependency on the tex package?  that's probably possible but a question for a linux help site, not here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

David's answer

> [Prevention of tex packages] is exactly what a package manager like apt-get does, and your test with kile shows it worked, you installed kile but that did not trigger an installation of the system tex as you had told apt that you already had an equivalent package.